# Showing Viewcontrollers modally in a delege functions

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have some code that shows two `UIViewController` in a delegate.

RootViewController.m

```
request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"***some https url here ***"]];
// custom implementation of NSURLConnectionDelegate
dataman = [[DataManager alloc] initWithParentcontroller:self]; 
mainConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:dataman];
```

In AuthenticationViewController.h

```
@protocol ShowAuthenticationWindowDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) onFinishedEnteringCredentials:(NSURLCredential*)credentials;
- (void) onCancelAuthentication;
@end
```

in AuthenticationViewController.m

```
- (IBAction) onClickLogin:(id)sender;
{
    ....
    // authDelegate => id <ShowAuthenticationWindowDelegate>
    [authDelegate onFinishedEnteringCredentials:credentials];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    ....
}
```

in DataManger.h  (DataManager class) implements the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `ShowAuthenticationWindowDelegate`.

In Datamanager.m
In the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate function I show the `AuthentiationViewController` as a modal dialog to gather username/password.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    AuthenticationViewController *authview = [[AuthenticationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthenticationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    authview.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    authview.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    authview.credentialsDelegate = self;
    [rootController presentModalViewController:authview animated:YES];
}
```

Here I show a `UIViewController` which is an activity indicator in a view. I am showing it modally after I dismiss the previous `AuthenticationViewController` dialog in one of the login button event handler by called `dismissModalViewController`. After sending the credentials with challenge object (previously cached) I am showing the ActivityViewController modally, but **it is not shown no matter what I do**. I tried to show an `UIAlertView` which works, but my activityviewcontroller is not shown. I checked the parameters and objects everything is valid. even the delegate wire ups!!! All the code is getting called but the dialog is not shown.

**May be I am missing something ???**

```
- (void) onFinishedEnteringCredentials:(NSURLCredential*)credentials;
{

    [[authChallenge sender] useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:authChallenge];
    // create an activity modal dialog 
    if (activityController == nil) {
        activityController = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        activityController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        activityController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    }
    [rootController presentModalViewController:activityController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the solution, if anyone want to show two modal dialogs back to back, you should set the "animated" parameter to "NO" on the controller that is being dismissed. It seems like the animation transition is not being completed by the time the next controller is shown with "presentViewController" function.